# Social Engine not updating profile photo on Amazon ec2

Tags: php, apache, amazon-ec2, socialengine

My social engine instance was working fine when i used to host in dreamhost server but after switching to AWS, updating profile photo is stopped working.

- Error msg on UI is "The image you selected was too large." even though image size is very less. some 2-6kb.
- Stack trace is mention below

```
2018-01-16T04:42:53+00:00 WARN (4): exception 'Engine_Image_Exception' with message 'No available adapter for image
operations' in
/var/www/html/social/application/libraries/Engine/Image.php:52 Stack
trace:
    #0 /var/www/html/social/application/modules/User/Model/User.php(159):
Engine_Image::factory()
    #1 /var/www/html/social/application/modules/User/controllers/EditController.php(133):
User_Model_User->setPhoto(Object(Engine_Form_Element_File))
    #2 /var/www/html/social/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Action.php(516):
User_EditController->photoAction()
    #3 /var/www/html/social/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Dispatcher/Standard.php(308):
Zend_Controller_Action->dispatch('photoAction')
    #4 /var/www/html/social/application/libraries/Zend/Controller/Front.php(954):
Zend_Controller_Dispatcher_Standard->dispatch(Object(Zend_Controller_Request_Http),
Object(Zend_Controller_Response_Http))
    #5 /var/www/html/social/application/modules/Core/Bootstrap.php(84):
Zend_Controller_Front->dispatch()
    #6 /var/www/html/social/application/libraries/Engine/Application.php(160):
Core_Bootstrap->run()
    #7 /var/www/html/social/application/index.php(219): Engine_Application->run()
    #8 /var/www/html/social/index.php(24): include('/var/www/html/s...')
    #9 {main}
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by installing php pluging called GD. It was there on my old sever but i forgot to install on my new ec2 server.